# Haskell: IO() inside a MonadLogger context

Tags: haskell, logging, io, monads

I want to implement actual email verification inside a Yesod application.  I'm horrified that the only example I can find -- http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/yesod-auth-account/tree/tests/Foundation.hs?id=1.2.0 -- uses unsafePerformIO.  Surely not ?  Here's my (uncompilable) code.  Is there a polite way to correct it?

```
module EmailVerification() where


import qualified Yesod.Core as YC
import qualified Yesod.Auth as YA
import qualified Yesod.Auth.Account as YAA
import qualified Foundation
import qualified Network.Mail.SMTP as SMTP
import qualified Network.Mail.Mime as Mime
import qualified Logging
import qualified Control.Monad.Logger as CML


instance YAA.AccountSendEmail Foundation.JRState where
    sendVerifyEmail uname email url = YC.getYesod >>= newAccountEmail uname email url
    sendNewPasswordEmail uname email url = YC.getYesod >>= resetAccountEmail uname email url


newAccountEmail, resetAccountEmail :: YC.MonadLogger m => Foundation.TextItem -> Foundation.TextItem -> Foundation.TextItem -> Foundation.JRState -> m ()
newAccountEmail uname email url state = do
    SMTP.sendMail "localhost" (makeEmail uname email url) -- barf
    logAccountEmail uname email url "Verification"


resetAccountEmail uname email url state = do
    SMTP.sendMail "localhost" (makeEmail uname email url)  -- also barf
    logAccountEmail uname email url "Reset password"


logAccountEmail :: YC.MonadLogger m => Foundation.TextItem -> Foundation.TextItem -> Foundation.TextItem -> String -> m ()
logAccountEmail uname email url action =
    Logging.logInfo $ Foundation.concat [ Foundation.pack action, Foundation.pack " email for ", uname, Foundation.pack " (", email, Foundation.pack "): ", url ]


makeEmail uname email url =
    Mime.Mail
        Mime.Address Nothing Foundation.nullText
        [ Mime.Address (Just uname) email ]
        [ ]
        [ ]
        [ ( Foundation.pack "Subject", Foundation.pack "JackRose Account" ) ]
        [ [ Foundation.concat [ Foundation.pack "Your URL is ", url ] ] ]
```

Comment: That example uses `unsafePerformIO` to create some global `IORef`s.  I cannot tell by looking why they are needed.  Do you even need global state? If not there shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: No;  I don't need global state (I think).  I just want (1) to send an email and (2) log the fact that an email was sent.